# implement background img for web animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to pull an image, and  the below isn't working. The result within the fiddle via the code below is just a black circle. I need the image to appear within this circle.

```
var context;
var dx= 4;
var dy=4;
var y=150;
var x=10;
function draw(){
    context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    context.beginPath();
    /* context.fillStyle="#0000ff"; */
    context.src = 'http://s22.postimg.org/8i2xyc8wt/coin.png'; 
    context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    if( x<0 || x>300)
    dx=-dx;
    if( y<0 || y>300)
        dy=-dy;
        x+=dx;
        y+=dy;
    }
setInterval(draw,10);
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ymwy1ao/2/).

Comment: The fiddle seems to works just fine for me ?

Comment: That looks like it's working for me? Can you be more specific

Comment: The animation is working.. but the image is not pulling in.

Comment: you need to use context.drawImage

Comment: here's a very nice article. hope this helps. https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/AnimatingtheCanvas/AnimatingtheCanvas.html

Comment: Are you getting [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `drawImage` instead of `arc` and `fill`.

```
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
context.drawImage(img,x,y);
```

(Assuming you have an element on your page like this. Pretty sure you can use the display:none to hide it, not 100% on that.)

```
<img id="scream" src="http://s22.postimg.org/8i2xyc8wt/coin.png" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: Yes, but how would the source of my image pull in?

Comment: Check the documentation for drawImage. You can give it the id of an image to draw. For example:
`<img id="scream" src="http://s22.postimg.org/8i2xyc8wt/coin.png" style="display:none;" />`
`var img=document.getElementById("scream");`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to draw the image inside the circle you need to use context.drawImage() after context.clip() like this

```
var context;
var dx= 4;
var dy=4;
var y=150;
var x=10;
var coin=new Image();//create new Image element
    coin.src='http://s22.postimg.org/8i2xyc8wt/coin.png';
    //you need to wait the load event in order to draw on canvas
function draw(){
    context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    context.beginPath();
    context.save();//save the context
    context.translate(x,y);//move to x y position
    context.arc(0,0,30,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.clip();//clip the image inside the circle
    //draw the image inside the circle drawImage(image,-r,-r,d,d)
    context.drawImage(coin,-30,-30,60,60);
    context.restore(); //restore the context position to (0,0)
    if( x<0 || x>300)
    dx=-dx;
    if( y<0 || y>300)
        dy=-dy;
        x+=dx;
        y+=dy;
    }
setInterval(draw,10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ymwy1ao/4/